# Can I tell Zeppelin to use my Python env? (pyenv/venv)

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I'm looking to make the switch from JupyterLab to Apache Zeppelin. One of the things that I liked about JupyterLab was that I could `pipenv install jupyter`, and then my Python code in the notebook was natively using my app's Python environment. This enabled me to run a shell that could talk directly to my app's models and views.

However, I like the Helium Packages (Spark/Beam/Neo4j/Bash) and Dynamic Forms of Zeppelin  in comparison to the ipython widgets/ nbextensions of the Jupyter ecosystem.

How can I tell Zeppelin to use my pyenv/venv when running `%python` cells?

---

**Info about my python venv**:

```
$ pyenv activate MY_APP

$ which python
/Users/ME/.pyenv/shims/python

$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
'/Users/ME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/MY_APP'
```

---

found this in **/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json** of docker image apache/zeppelin:0.8.1 but struggling more than usual to map a desktop volume.

```
"python": {
      "id": "python",
      "name": "python",
      "group": "python",
      "properties": {
        "zeppelin.python": {
          "name": "zeppelin.python",
          "value": "python",
          "type": "string"
        },
```

**inside zeppelin notebook**

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']

[1] '/zeppelin/interpreter/python/py4j-0.9.2/src'
```

---

I'm sure I could pull this off with `%sh` bash commands inside a live notebook, but is there a way I can ***set the python env in a zeppelin config***?

Comment: SOLVED =  set `zeppelin.python` to the output of `sys.executable` in the python section of the localhost:8080/#/interpreters page

Comment: Instead of posting a single comment I invite you to post an answer and mark it as correct in 2 days.

Comment: @eyllanesc forgot that you can provide your own answer immediately... just not accept it

Comment: You can only accept your own answer after 2 days published your question, therefore you can not accept it, you just have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out your Python executable

```
$ pyenv activate my_env
(my_env) $ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable

/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/my_env/bin/python
```

Then navigate browser to `localhost:8080/#/interpreters` and search for python.

Change `zeppelin.python` to the output of `sys.executable`

Save + Restart zeppelin

You'll also want to change `zeppelin.pyspark.python` to the same path as the spark's pyspark interpreter won't infer the path of your regular python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Zeppelin developers, you can also set it inline in a notebook cell.

```
%python.conf

zeppelin.python <your_python_env_path>
```